# How to compare two rdds in Spark?

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, count, rdd

I have loaded 2 csv files into two spark RDD's, one containing country codes and second containing tweet data. I am trying find the following:

1. how many different countries are mentioned in the tweets?
2. compute the total number of times any country is mentioned.

Code:

```
country_lines = sc.textFile('country-data.csv')
words = country_lines.flatMap( lambda country_lines: country_lines.split(" )")
country_tuples = words.map(lambda word : (word, 1))
countryDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(country_tuples, ["country" , "code"])

tweets = sc.textFile("tweet_data.csv")
```

I am trying to find how many time each country in the CountryDF occurs in the tweets csv (there is only column with the tweet text).

country_DF looks like this:

```
Afghanistan  AFG
Albania  ALB
Algeria  ALG
American Samoa   ASA
Andorra  AND
```

How do I count the occurrence of each country in the tweets pyspark rdd using python?

Answer (score 0):

You can group tweetDF to get the count of each country in tweet.csv and then join with countryDF to get the count.

```
df =  tweetDF.groupby("CountryName").count().join(countryDF,["CountryName"])
```